# Gmail API returns 403 forbidden and no other messages (other API's working fine)

Tags: .net, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client, gmail-api

I've got an application with several successful Google API integrations. I'm hitting a roadblock trying to add Gmail integration into the mix. I'm using the .NET API, Google.Apis.Gmail.v1 (version 1.9.0.140).

Here's my code showing a successful Drive API call followed by the Gmail API call that fails:

```
var drive = new DriveService(Context.GoogleOAuthInitializer);
var list = drive.Files.List().Execute();
Console.WriteLine(list.Items.Count);
// Output: 100 (first page of results)

var gmail = new GmailService(Context.GoogleOAuthInitializer);
var result = gmail.Users.Drafts.List("me").Execute();
// Throws exception described below
```

The .NET exception provides this information:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Forbidden [403]
Errors [
    Message[Forbidden] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]
]
```

I'm using the following scopes to get the OAuth token. When I added the gmail scope, I was (as expected) prompted again by Google, "Do you want to give this application access to your email?" I also enabled the gmail API in the Google API Console.

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudprint
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://mail.google.com/
    * https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose was tried as well
```

Really wish there was something more helpful in the message to point me in the right direction!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had rolled my own OAuth implementation, and I had this code to add the authorization header:

```
void IConfigurableHttpClientInitializer.Initialize(ConfigurableHttpClient httpClient) {
    string auth = string.Format("AuthSub token=\"{0}\"", GoogleOAuthToken);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", auth);
}
```

and this worked fine for the Drive, CloudPrint, and Contacts API's, but for some reason the Gmail API's needed this:

```
void IConfigurableHttpClientInitializer.Initialize(ConfigurableHttpClient httpClient) {
    string auth = string.Format("Bearer {0}", GoogleOAuthToken);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", auth);
}
```

Makes sense, I guess, although I don't know why the API's would act differently.

**Edit:** Use of AuthSub for the Google API's has been deprecated: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthSub

Comment: OAuth or OAuth 2 ?

Comment: @PreguntonCojoneroCabrón OAuth 2.

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail API is newer than those and doesn't accept older authentication formats that other Google APIs may--it only accepts oauth2.  I wouldn't roll your own authentication, there should be reasonable libraries for doing it in .net.

Comment: I wouldn't either, today. :) Two years ago when this project first went to production the reasonableness of the available libraries was a little different. And the basic OAuth2 token exchange isn't terribly involved.